# How to call external application with arguments in python on mac osx

Tags: python, macos, subprocess, osx-mavericks, easygui

I am using mac osx 10.9 and python 2.7  From one main app code, I want to call another application dailogbox.app present in /Applications location. dailogbox.app requires two arguments title and message as arguments. 
So, how to call from main app code this dailogbox.app with these two arguments to pass.

dailogbox.py code is :

```
import sys
import easygui
msg=(sys.argv)[1]
title=(sys.argv)[2]
easygui.msgbox(msg,title)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `dialogbox.app` is a normal OS X application, you can use the `open` command to run it.

```
import subprocess
msg=sys.argv[1]
title=sys.argv[2]
subprocess.call(["open", "dialogbox.app", "--args", msg, title])
```

Comment: dialogbox.app should be called from  main code. main code passses arguments to dialogbox.app code